# DocuSign automation

Tags: docusignapi

In my current project we have a requirement to have a Digital signature on all the invoices before it is sent out to customers. Considering the volume of the invoices/Credit memos we would like to automate DocuSign e-signature process. I was wonder if it is possible to insert a e-signature without any human signing it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Properly approved and constructed business processes can sign documents by themselves via delegated authority. DocuSign supports this type of signing via the [DocuSign Signature Appliance](https://www.docusign.com/products/hybrid-cloud-appliances).

Invoices that are digitally signed with a company's certificate are a frequent use case for delegated automated signing.

Signature authority can be delegated (see this [example](https://opsmanual.uiowa.edu/administrative-financial-and-facilities-policies/facsimile-signatures-and-signature-assignment-2)) and can be delegated to a well-understood automated process. But the system needs to be carefully set up and should be vetted by counsel.

### Added

To be clear, the DocuSign cloud eSignature product does not support programmatic signing of documents/envelopes.

Comment: Note "Electronic Signature" and "Digital Signature" are not the same thing. 
You can do what you ask if you chose to use Digital Signature with the DocuSign Appliance. 
You cannot do it using eSignature only.